# Extracting text from pdf using objective-c(libz.dylib)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, linker-errors

I have imported the pdf.h file in my view controller class and tried calling

```
NSString *outPutString = convertPDF(pathToPdfFile);
```

but while building it gives me **linker error**:

`_convertPDF" refrenced from: -[ScriptViewController searchBarSearchButtonClicked:] in ScriptViewController.o Symbol(s) not found`

I have also included libz.dylib in my project.

What am I doing wrong?

Is there any step to be followed before building the project which includes c code?

**Also one more question:**

Will this search algorithm work on any PDF(simple and formatted pdfs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your must use the definition in the  **pdf.h**

```
#if __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

NSString* convertPDF(NSString * pathToFile);

#if __cplusplus
}   
#endif
```

also in the implementation  file **pdf.m**m   use:

```
#if __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

 NSString* convertPDF(NSString * pathToFile); 

#if __cplusplus
} //Extern C
#endif
```

Answer (score 4):

What if you change the name of the .m file that calls pdf.h to xxxx.mm ? It's a c++ file.
I tested it and found out it works only with simple ascii pdfs.