# Get text from a pdf in NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am trying to make an iOS app which would extract plain text from a pdf file and display it in a `UITextView`. Its simply not a pdf reader to view a pdf file but i would later wish to perform certain operations on that text. 
I have already googled a lot but still not able to get an exact solution.

i already tried using https://github.com/zachron/pdfiphone 
but the files are using ARMV6 architecture which seems obsolete with xcode 4.5

And if anyone can suggest some exact and non-confusing code using Quartz-2d framework of iOS then it would be great.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://github.com/zachron/pdfiphone) is An Sample code to Extract text from PDF Hope this Might Help You.

https://github.com/zachron/pdfiphone

This is a library to get the text out of a PDF for the iPhone.

Another Demo is there Which uses [OCR technology](https://github.com/nolanbrown/Tesseract-iPhone-Demo) find the link below

https://github.com/nolanbrown/Tesseract-iPhone-Demo

Also Check t[his page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf_scan/dq_pdf_scan.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH220-TPXREF101) of the [Quartz 2D Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007533-SW1), it covers everything you need to open and parse a PDF file in iOS. Note that it is not a simple task, since there's no method to extract the full text in one line. You have to work with the data as an input stream, using a `CGPDFScanner`

Two Other Libraries

1. https://github.com/KurtCode/PDFKitten/
2. https://github.com/mobfarm/FastPdfKit

Comment: Sir i already searched for ZACHRON but the code that he has works only with armv6 and current XCODE version supports armv7 which gives a compiler issue while compiling with those classes.

Comment: So better Update your Question with What Already you Tried And what are the issue you Facing . Then you will surely get perfect Answer for your question.

Comment: I have updated my question... Please see and try if you can provide me with another useful link

Answer (score 2):

This question comes up all the time. It is VERY hard to extract text from PDF in general. The PDF specification is not designed with text extraction in mind. There are many libraries that try to do the job, essentially by reconstructing the text from the geometric placement of the individual glyphs. These libraries have varying degrees of success, but will all fail on certain PDF documents. In fact, some PDF documents have Glyphs but no way to associate the glyph with a character. For these documents it is simply not possible to extract text, short of using some kind of OCR approach.

PDF is designed as a read-only format that is portable in the sense that a PDF document will be rendered identically on any platform. That is what it is best at, and what it should be used for.

If text is to be edited, do not use PDF.

Answer (score 0):

[Here (Extracting text from pdf using objective-c)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384916/extracting-text-from-pdf-using-objective-clibz-dylib), I found an answer to your question and it works. But not so fine as i need it :(

- it can extract only ascii
- it return me only one paragraph

Good luck.