# Swift iOS - How to show multi page PDF

Tags: ios, swift

How can I split a multi-page PDF file into single pages in an array using Swift?

I have a six page PDF document that I would like to display using webview with a nice page turning effect. The first part is done, displaying some html text on each page, but I would like to display pages from a PDF document instead.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: These links may help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960195/extracting-pdf-text-in-objective-c

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037328/get-text-from-a-pdf-in-nsstring

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but I'm looking to display the whole page, images and all, plus using Swift.

Comment: When you talk about the six page PDF document, is it static, as in are you going to use only this document, or you want something generic that would work with any number of pages PDF document?

Comment: @pteofil For starters there is just one static pdf file I would like to show. Maybe a couple of more at a later stage, so something that was generic would be magic.

Comment: Here's an easy way to do it. Not too performant though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19154484/

Comment: The best way it's to draw the pages yourself with CoreGraphics. But it seems a bit too much work for what you need.

Comment: @pteofil Thanks for your help. I will have a go at it. Might have to stay with objc on this part.