# Swift 2 - PDF document paging

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, paging

I'm looking at a way of displaying a multi-page pdf file with paging.

The pdf file may be any number of pages (likely between 1 and 8).

I need to split the pdf document up into separate pages, save these as an array so I can then display this array as separate page son a paging application.

I've seen this stack overflow question, which pretty much sums up what I want to achieve: [Swift iOS - How to show multi page PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30394045/swift-ios-how-to-show-multi-page-pdf)

But not quite understanding the answer. Any further advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use a `UIScrollView` with its paging property set to `YES`. See for example [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ScrollViewPagingMode/ScrollViewPagingMode.html) part of the apple documentation.

You only need three subviews of the scroll view (see the documentation), but start off more simply with one subview for each page in the PDF document.

You should not try to "split" the PDF document into pages - instead, keep a single reference to the same `CGPDFDocument` in each subview. Use the page number to get the correct page to display in the subview. You will need to transform the PDF page from PDF page space to the coordinate space of your view.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your help. However I keep getting the pdf scrolling vertically through the pages instead of paging. I've not used paging before and while I can get it to page through different pdf's when saved as an array i.e. doc1, doc2 etc, I can't seem to have the paging work between pages of a single document. If there is a tutorial / sample code of paging though pages of single pdf document then that would be greatly appreciated.