# How to convert NSData with textEncoding utf-8 into NSURL

Tags: ios, objective-c, encoding, nsdata, nsurl

I want to convert NSData (textEncoding utf-8) into NSURL.
I am writing below code for this, but conversion from NSData to NSString returning nil. (May be due to encoding type)

```
NSString *stringFromData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; // stringFromData is nil after execution of this line.
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:stringFromData];
```

So what should I do to convert NSData into NSURL in my case.

But when I am trying to load this data into webview, Its working good. Here is my code to load this data into webview.

```
[self.webView loadData:myData MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil]; //PDF is showing in my webview.
```

but I am not able to convert this NSData into NSURL. What encoding should I use to convert NSData with textEncoding utf-8 into NSURL ?

Comment: I am not able to convert NSData into NSURL.

Comment: I gess that's useless, `@"You can't convert this string/data into NSURL, it will always retrun ni"` unless or until it is actually a url e.g. `http://www.google.com"`

Comment: If it is a actually an url (Already URL) then what is need to convert into NSURL? Its a data and I want to convert this data into url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to load data that represents a PDF into an `NSString`. A PDF file does not consist of UTF-8 encoded characters that represent text, it's a file that contains header information, fonts, vector graphics AND text.

The only solution to your problem in my mind is change the source of the `NSData` to something that will provide UTF-8 encoded characters that make up a URL.

If you can't get data any other way, why not check if you can extract the textual data from the PDF? https://github.com/zachron/pdfiphone

Comment: Ok...So what should I do to convert my data into nsurl?

Comment: Change your data. Where is it coming from?

Comment: Think of your problem this way: You have an image that if you open it in an image viewer you see the text "www.thisisanimage.com". Now you're trying to take this binary data that represents the image file and load it into a string and you're expecting the STRING to say "www.thisisanimage.com". Get it?

Comment: I got your point... but I need to convert this data into url. Is there any way?

Comment: And here's another possible solution if the above doesn't work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384916/extracting-text-from-pdf-using-objective-clibz-dylib

Comment: Your effort is appreciated, but I want to implement the open in functionality (UIDocumentInteraction to show options of installed app which can open PDF)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried writing the data to local file,

```
NSString *docPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/Documents"];
NSString *pdfFilePath = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"pdfFile.pdf"];
BOOL success =  [myData writeToFile:pdfFilePath atomically:YES];
if (success) {
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:pdfFilePath];
    NSLog(@"url from data : %@",url);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks

Comment: Yes... I know this approach will work, but I don't want to write the data in local file due to security purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try this:

```
//Convert data to string
     NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
//Convert the string to URL
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```